# Removing a branch hosted with gitosis

Tags: git, version-control, gitosis

I have a git repo hosted on my server using gitosis. I had branches master and template, I renamed the template branch to develop and pushed the develop branch to the gitosis repo which created a new branch named develop, but if I look in the repo_dir/refs/heads dir of my gitosis repo the template branch is still there, how can I remove this branch from the repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know gitosis but I don't see why it would be any different

```
$ git push origin :template
```

The above command will delete the branch from your origin.

Comment: I know gitosis and it's the same. The only problem could be `receive.denyDeletes` setting on target repo.